# Prove that $d i_p (T_p S) = ${ $x\in T_P M : x(f)=0 $ whenever $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$ with $f|_s \equiv0$}

Tags: analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This question was part of my smooth manifolds assignment and I need help in proving one side.

> Prove that $d i_p (T_p S) = ${ $x\in T_P M : x(f)=0 $ whenever $f \in C^{\infty} (M)$ with $f|_s \equiv0$}, here $i_p$ is inclusion map and S is a submanifold of M, P is any point lying in S.

Attempt: If $v\in T_P(S)$ then there exists a function $f\in C^{\infty} (M)$, $di_P(v)(f)=v(f(i))$. If $f|S \equiv 0$, then $v(f(i))=0$ .Hence $di_p(T_pS)\subseteq ${$x\in T_P M : x(f)=0 $ if $f|_S=0$}.

But I need help in proving the converse part.

Can you please help with that?

Answer (score 1):

I identify $T_pS$ with its image under the the differential induced by the inclusion.

You have:

$T_pS\subseteq  \{v\in T_pM$ $:$ $vf=0$ whenever $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ for which $f|_{S}=0$ $\}$ $\star$

Reverse direction:

For $p\in S$ choose a chart $(U,x^1,...,x^n)$ about $p$ for which $U\cap S$ is defined by the vanishing of the coordinates $x^{k+1},...,x^n=0$. Thus $\{\partial_1,...,\partial_k\}$ forms a basis for the right hand side in $\star$.

Comment: Can you please tell how you wrote that $T_p S\subseteq $ {$ v]in T_p M: ...$} in the third line of your answer?

Comment: @Mohammed can you please reply to my above comment?